# Ratings Bar Showing Streaks Under Stars

Tags: android, android-layout

Can't really understand why this is happening. There are lines under all my custom rating bars

[Rating Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X47kv.png)

Here is the drawable I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/star_disabled" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_disabled" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_enabled" />
```

Here is the XML

```
   <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ratings_bar"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:rating="3"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar"
                android:numStars="5" />
```

Does any have a clue on how to fix this? Really not sure what is wrong. The image obviously does contain long streaky marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this in the past. Use a `layout_margin` in the `RatingBar`. Also, I suspect that the images that you are for the stars may not have any margin themselves and the stars are touching the border of the image. Try to use a slightly smaller star image, with a little white margin (not transparent) in the image itself, to avoid this problem

Comment: Yea adding a margin to the image itself helped thanks

Comment: @BMK can you post the solution?